# Trouble creating newlines

Tags: line-breaking

Input to `latex.exe`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}{\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont

cccc
\\
dddd
\newline
eeee
\par
ffff
\hfill \break
gggg}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Hi, how do you make newlines correctly so that `\\` causes a newline?  Am I missing packages?

The blue and red grid background are part of my app, not latex output.

Comment: Don't use \\ to start a new line unless you're in an environment (like `tabular` or `align`) that requires it. A new line can be achieved by hitting return twice in your source. This starts a new paragraph. Use `\noindent` if you wish. Also, don't do this in the `standalone` class. Use `article` instead.

Comment: @SandyG I think i need standalone because the output is images that are graphics in a scene of an app.  If I use article, won't there be big margins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the `standalone` class doesn't make paragraphs. Here is a way to override this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}{\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont
cccc
\\
dddd
\newline
eeee
\par
ffff
gggg}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]